# Weighted voting in the UN

Tags: united-nations, voting-systems

Is any voting in the UN ever weighted against the population, contribution or consequences?

I understand that some countries have a better footing due to historical reasons. However, just to name some countries not in the security council: I find puzzling that Lichtenstein (pop. 38,137) or Tuvalu (pop. 11,792) get one vote in the same way that India (pop. 1.38 billion) or Indonesia (272 mill.) get one too.

Comment: Well, if you don't pay your dues, you [can't vote](https://www.dw.com/en/iran-venezuela-and-sudan-and-others-lose-un-voting-rights/a-60405261) at the UNGA, so that's proportional to contribution in a sense, if by contribution you mean financial.

Comment: @fizz Interesting. Are all countries paying the same amount?

Comment: If you were Lichtenstein would you think it was fair that your country had practically no useful votes under a system where it was weighted by population count or how much money you paid in ?  I doubt it.  Would the US and Russia be happy if China or India had more votes than they did ?  I doubt they would.

Comment: To downvoters:  the question is simple and clear.  While it seems a bit pushy with the Tuvalu vs India comparison, it is also necessary to illustrate the issue at hand.  If you have a problem with the idea of weighted voting, write an answer as a rebuttal.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine: Notice: weighted voting against a factor does not mean you have linear proportional voting power in relation to this factor. Weighted/proportional are different relations.

Answer (score 4):

- In the General Assembly, each country has a vote. Votes can be suspended over unpaid dues. These are assessed through a formula which is based on GNI and debt (i.e. capacity to pay), but with a floor and a cap.

  - The cap affects the US, so others could be said to be 'overpaying.' With about a quarter of the economy of the US, Japan pays one third of the dues.
  - *Many* countries are slightly late in their payments, often due to the national budgeting cycle. The UN expects payments in January. A few countries are much later.
- In the Security Council, five countries have a permanent seat and veto power, and ten countries are elected on a rotating basis. The veto powers are the main winners of WWII.

Answer (score 4):

No.

[UNITED NATIONS SECURITY COUNCIL](https://www.un.org/securitycouncil/content/voting-system)

> Each member of the Security Council shall have one vote.

[General Assembly](https://interactive.aljazeera.com/aje/2019/how-has-my-country-voted-at-unga/index.html)

> In the UN General Assembly, the rule is: One country, one vote for the delegations that come from every member state.

Now, while one country, one vote has a lot going against it, from your examples and common sense, what's unclear is what a clear, fair and *simple* system to replace it would be.

*By population*?  Sure, have India and China call all the shots.  *By contribution*?  For sure, have all the poor countries not have a say at all.  I mean, that's already more or less the case, why not formalize it?  *By consequence*???

As an example of the pitfalls, look at the population weighting inherent in the US Electoral College and see how controversial it has become, even though it is far from a linear progression.  The fact that it weighs in the opposite direction from the OP's question - giving smaller states bigger power - still doesn't change the angle that it tries to adjust a *simple* metric - population - and then layers on 2 automatic electors per state.  It's complex and coefficient-based and that complexity attracts controversy from those who lose out from it.

Which in the case of population weighting would be pretty much every country other than India, China and big-ish or big-ish-to-be poorer countries like Brazil, Indonesia, Nigeria and Pakistan.

Comment: Notice: weighted voting against a factor does not mean you have linear proportional voting power in relation to this factor.  Weighted/proportional are different relations.

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica. I think it could be possible by weighing, but you need to use many criteria, and each criteria carries its own weight. This also gives countries the drive to improve in order to get a higher weighted vote in the next year.

Comment: @JoeyJoystick what it lacks is clarity and objectivity.  Each country would prefer weights to its best advantage.

Comment: The main remedy is that votes by the UN as a whole don't mean much, rather like the House of Lords.